# Ubuntu 64 bit crashes

Tags: 12.10, firefox, 64-bit

I installed 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10 recently on a freshly formatted hard drive. My problem is that whenever I open a program like Firefox or Thunderbird there's a pause and then my screen goes black for a second and it logs me out.

The software center works and I can access terminal just not programs. My specs are 8 GB DDR3 RAM, i5 3570k CPU, NVIDIA gtx 670 graphics card and a 650 GB hard drive.

I can run 32 bit version of Ubuntu without problems.

Any ideas? 
edit: steam also crashes when it opens up, I can log into but when it actually opens up it crashes as well. thevwirdest thing is that ive reinstalled ubuntu like 4 times now, samething everytime. I'm installing it from USB though. also tried re downloading it to USB multiple times. and I tried going into the live USB THEN installing as well as installing from the menu.

Comment: Have you installed any graphics drivers?

Comment: Yes but the problem happened before and after, and I'm talking directly after a fresh install, still crashes.

Comment: Odd thing is that the Software Center runs! Is your problem **only** with Firefox and Thunderbird? Which are **all** the programs that cause a log out and those that don't? Please edit your question with the information.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?